# Rename tag [compositetype] to [composite-types]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I suggest to rename [compositetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compositetype) to [composite-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composite-types).
Seems more correct and consistent with the existing, more common tags [anonymous-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anonymous-types) or [primitive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive-types) et al.

Comment: I don't think there's any well-established convention for this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, not really. We would be establishing it. Would be *consistent* at least.